# chmod command is not working in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script that needs to create a file if an argument is passed to he script.
If no argument is passed then it will ask for fileName but it needs to have default permission as `-rwx- --- - ---`.
I am using this command `chmod a=-rwx` to remove all the default permissions and then i am using `chmod u=+rwx` to get the desired permission as stated but it is not working.
Can anyone help please?

```
#!bin\bash

if [ $#==0 ]; then
    echo "Please enter a file name?"
    read fileName
    if [ -f $fileName ]; then
        echo "File already exist! Opening for Editing"
        sleep 3
        nano $fileName
    else
        echo "File created with the name $fileName"
        echo "Opening $fileName for editing "
        sleep 3
        echo "#!bin\bash" >$fileName
        nano $fileName
    fi
elif [ -f $1 ]; then
    echo "File already exists with the name $1"
    echo "Opening for editing"
    sleep 3
    nano $1
else
    fileName="$1"
    chmod a=-rwx $fileName
    chmod u=+rwx $fileName
    echo "File created with the name $filename"
    echo "Opening $fileName for editing "
    echo "#!bin\bash" >$fileName
    sleep 3
    nano $1

fi
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Check your script with [Shell Check](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to catch various basic syntax errors.

Comment: "is not working" isn't helpful. Are you getting an error message? what *is* it doing? c.f. [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to asking a question well.

Comment: No there is no error actually 
But permissions with chmod are not being applied

Comment: Show the before, the after, and the output. Use `set -x`.

Comment: It's not `=+` and `=-`, it's either, `=`, `+` or `-`.

Comment: Don't use the relative syntax for chmod.  If you want permissions to be 0700, use `chmod 700 "$fileName"`

Comment: `#!bin\bash`?!  If you can't put in the effort to print actual code, why should anyone spend time reading the question?

Answer (score 1):

Your `chmod` syntax is incorrect. The operation is either `=` to set the mode to a specific value, `+` to add modes, or `-` to remove modes; you can't combine them with `=+` and `=-`.

You can perform multiple operations on a single file by separating them with `,`.

So it should be:

```
chmod go-rwx,u+rwx "$fileName"
```

Another problem:

```
if [ $#==0 ]
```

should be

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
```

Use `-eq` for numeric comparisons, and spaces are needed around operators in shell conditions.

Third problem: You're doing the `chmod` *before* you create the file. Put it after

```
echo "#!/bin/bash" >"$fileName"
```

Fourth problem: `#!bin\bash` should be `#!/bin/bash`.

Finally, remember to quote your variables, in case they contain spaces.

Comment: Yes you are right it works but from ubuntu terminal 
not inside from script 
If i use from terminal it changes permission 
but doesn't affect from shell script and that's probably because of opening nano text editor from this sript

Comment: You're opening nano after you change the permissions.

Comment: You're only doing the `chmod` in the case where the file doesn't exist, and you're doing it before you create the file. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: Then should i use touch command to first create the file 
and then apply these permissions?

Comment: The `echo` command will create the file, you just have to do the `chmod` after that.

Comment: You should have been getting errors from `chmod` saying that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Now it doesn't throw an error actually but i got your point you are write 
the problem is same as you found

Comment: Also, you're not doing the `chmod` in the case where you prompt for the filename. It would be better if you didn't repeat all that code in both cases. Just set `fileName` at the top to either `$1` or the user input, then use the same code to edit the file after creating it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the actual path of chmod:
Ex: `which chmod`

/usr/bin/chmod

In your script add the complete path of chmod and try it out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).